# If the other script expects user input, i want to write a script to automatically fill in that information

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line

I want to automate another program or script. If the other script expects user input, i want to write a script to automatically fill in that information.

When log in to host using putty one script runs automatically and require option input to proceed further. i want to provide that option from another script. This entire procedure should be completely automated using dos batch file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways and utilities,

If it is just single input then you can use < operator

```
#  some task
#
your script which needs input < $var (which contains input)  
#
#  post processing
```

if input is complex then you can try [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) utility

like,

```
#  some task
#
your_code.expec 
#
#  post processing
```

some examples are [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)

Comment: I think this solution does not work in a Windows/Dos batch .bat file. Is there a Windows version of `expect` utility?

Comment: @Nachiket, thanks for reply however i guess my questions bit confusing... my problem is when i login through putty on host then one terminal window pop up which is asking for option to select. Now i have prepare batch file which will automate login procedure but i am not able to provide option input through that batch file. Is it possible to provide option value???

Comment: see, pop up is part of UI which cannot be automated directly, but if possible you can try providing some options while logging in, examples. ssh uname@host -p port etc. which will pass the option directly in command so you will not get that pop up asking for options, is it possible in your case?

Comment: No because that is in login script which runs automatically whenever i logged in using putty or winscp... and that script needs input :(. I am searching alot but not getting any thing which would help me :(